# Kernel adapted from CUDA documentation giving incorrect result

Tags: cuda

I have copied the kernel from [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/archive/11.6.2/cuda-c-best-practices-guide/index.html#shared-memory-in-matrix-multiplication-c-aa__optimized-version-coalesced-reads-global-memory) and added one extra argument.

However, it seems to be not giving correct result.

Without transpose:

```
Result:
     5     17     29     41
    17     61    105    149
    29    105    181    257
    41    149    257    365
```

With transpose:

```
Result:
    11     14     17     20
    35     46     57     68
    59     78     97    116
    83    110    137    164
```

The correct result should be:

```
Result Matrix:
    90    100    110    120
   202    228    254    280
   314    356    398    440
   426    484    542    600
```

What is incorrect in my modified source code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

#define M 4
#define TILE_DIM 2

__global__ void coalescedMultiply(int *a, int*bT, int *c)
{
    __shared__ int aTile[TILE_DIM][TILE_DIM]; 
    __shared__ int transposedTile[TILE_DIM][TILE_DIM];

    int row = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    int col = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

    int sum = 0.0f;

    aTile[threadIdx.y][threadIdx.x] = a[row * M + threadIdx.x];
    transposedTile[threadIdx.x][threadIdx.y] = bT[(blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.y) * M + threadIdx.x];
    __syncthreads();

    for (int i = 0; i < TILE_DIM; i++)
    {
        sum += aTile[threadIdx.y][i] * transposedTile[i][threadIdx.x];
    }

    c[row * M + col] = sum;
}

void printMatrix(int *mat, int rr, int cc) {
  for (int i = 0; i < rr; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < cc; j++) {
      cout << setw(6) << mat[i * cc + j] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
  }
  cout << endl;
}

void initMatrix(int *mat, int rr, int cc) {
  int init = 1;
  for (int i = 0; i < rr; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < cc; j++) {
      mat[i * cc + j] = init++;
    }
  }
}

void initMatrixZero(int *mat, int rr, int cc) {
  for (int i = 0; i < rr; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < cc; j++) {
      mat[i * cc + j] = 0;
    }
  }
}

void transposeMatrix(const int *mat, int rr, int cc, int *result) {
  for (int i = 0; i < rr; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < cc; j++) {
      result[j * rr + i] = mat[i * cc + j];
    }
  }
}

int main()
{
    int N = M * M;
    int *a, *b, *bT, *c;
    int *dev_a, *dev_b, *dev_bT, *dev_c;

    // Allocate memory on the host
    a  = (int *)malloc(N * sizeof(int));
    b  = (int *)malloc(N * sizeof(int));
    bT = (int *)malloc(N * sizeof(int));
    c  = (int *)malloc(N * sizeof(int));

    // Initialize input data
    initMatrix(a, M, M);
    initMatrix(b, M, M);
    initMatrixZero(bT, M, M);
    transposeMatrix(b, M, M, bT);
    initMatrixZero(c, M, M);

    printMatrix(a, M, M);
    printMatrix(b, M, M);
    printMatrix(bT, M, M);

    // Allocate memory on the device
    cudaMalloc((void **) &dev_a,  N * sizeof(int));
    cudaMalloc((void **) &dev_b,  N * sizeof(int));
    cudaMalloc((void **) &dev_bT, N * sizeof(int));
    cudaMalloc((void **) &dev_c,  N * sizeof(int));

    // Copy input data from host to device
    cudaMemcpy(dev_a,   a, N * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(dev_b,   b, N * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(dev_bT, bT, N * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemset(dev_c,   0, N * sizeof(int));

    // Define grid and block dimensions
    dim3 blockSize(TILE_DIM, TILE_DIM);
    dim3 gridSize(M/TILE_DIM, M/TILE_DIM);

    // Launch the kernel
    coalescedMultiply<<<gridSize, blockSize>>>(dev_a, dev_b,  dev_c);
    //coalescedMultiply<<<gridSize, blockSize>>>(dev_a, dev_bT, dev_c);
    

    // Copy the result from device to host
    cudaMemcpy(c, dev_c, N * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    // Print the result
    printf("Result:\n");
    printMatrix(c, M, M);

    // Free memory on the device
    cudaFree(dev_a);
    cudaFree(dev_c);

    // Free memory on the host
    free(a);
    free(c);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I gather you never tried running the original kernel in the documentation in your test harness. If you had done that, you would have realized that it also doesn't produce the answer your are expecting, because the kernel code doesn't do what you think it does. Read the original kernel code carefully

Comment: @talonmies, *because the kernel code doesn't do what you think it does* --- then what does it do?

Comment: It multiplies **one tile** of size `TILE_DIM`  of the problem `dot(A^T,A)` where A is a row major matrix of stride `M`

Comment: @talonmies, That was not explicity written ...

Comment: Every a cursory examination of the code makes that extremely obvious to anyone who can understand a for loop.... Change `TILE_DIM` to 4 and see what happens. Then ask yourself why.

Comment: The kernel code is missing the loop that strides from tile to tile that you would find in an ordinary shared memory tiled matrix multiply code, such as is presented [earlier in that programming guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#shared-memory).   The programming guide often assumes you have absorbed content that has been presented previously, before presenting more advanced content.  Each snippet of the programming guide is not a fully self-contained tutorial in and of itself, from first principles.

Comment: Since you are asking about code presented in section 9.2.3.3, you are expected to already know the directly relevant concepts presented earlier in section 3.2.4. The loop that is present in the code in 3.2.4 is this one: `for (int m = 0; m < (A.width / BLOCK_SIZE); ++m) {`  That is the tile-striding loop.  It (and anything like it) is absent from the code in 9.2.3.3, therefore the code in 9.2.3.3 could not stride from one tile to another, as it is accumulating its running product-sum for the output element.  Therefore the code presented in 9.2.3.3 only handles **one tile**.

Comment: @RobertCrovella, why not post an answer combining those two comments?

Comment: If you're convinced those two comments together provide an answer, why don't you post an answer? You're certainly allowed to answer your own questions on SO.  And it's not like the reference to the shared memory tiled matrix multiply code in the programming guide should be any great revelation to you .  I have pointed it out to you on several occasions, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76895262/1695960) is another example. Anyone is allowed to answer any SO question at any time, regardless of what other people have done. Furthermore there is no obligation for me, or anyone else, to answer.

Comment: I think there is significant value in people answering their own questions. One obvious point is that it means that I don't need to consider or try to write an answer; that saves me time. Second, what I have observed is that when someone writes their own answer, it usually means they understand the problem and its solution to the point that they reach comprehension. I believe that is an important objective, and there is no guarantee of that when I write an answer. Often, when I comment, its because I am not really sure where the stumbling block is. Writing an answer then may be less productive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The kernel you adapted is basically this after macro expansion/constant substitution:

```
__global__ void coalescedMultiply(float *a, float *c)
{
    __shared__ float aTile[2][2],
                     transposedTile[2][2];
    int row = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    int col = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int sum = 0;
    aTile[threadIdx.y][threadIdx.x] = a[row*4+threadIdx.x];
    transposedTile[threadIdx.x][threadIdx.y] =
        a[(blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.y)*4 +
        threadIdx.x];  
    __syncthreads();
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        sum += aTile[threadIdx.y][i]* transposedTile[i][threadIdx.x];
    }
    c[row*4+col] = sum;
}
```

This kernel loads two 2x2 sized chunks of the input array,  one in normal order, and one in transposed order, and outputs the dot product of those two chunks.

With your input array

```
  [[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
   [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
   [ 9, 10, 11, 12],
   [13, 14, 15, 16]]
```

and your tile size of 2 and block size of (2,2), the first block will load

```
   aTile = [[ 1, 2 ]
            [ 5, 6 ]]

   TransposedTile = [[ 1, 5 ]
                     [ 2, 6 ]]
```

and the dot product of those is:

```
 [[ 5, 17],
  [17, 61]]
```

Look familiar? Repeat the exercise for the other three blocks of the four your launched and you will get

```
[[1, 2],     dot  [[ 9, 13],  = [[ 29, 41
 [5, 6]]           [10, 14]]     [105,149]]

[[ 9, 10 ],  dot  [[1, 5],    = [[29, 105
 [ 13, 14]]         2, 6]]       [41, 149]]

[[ 9, 10 ],  dot  [[ 9, 13],  = [[181, 257
 [ 13, 14]]         10, 14]]     [257, 365]]
```

Those are the four quadrants of the solution matrix your code produces:

```
     5     17  |   29     41
    17     61  |  105    149
  -------------+--------------
    29    105  |  181    257
    41    149  |  257    365
```

i.e. the code you have run is returning
the correct result, which is calculating the dot product of four 2x2 submatrices within the supplied 4x4 matrices, the right matrix being transposed before the product is performed.

Your problem is that you misunderstood what the code you copied does. Apparently you want to calculate the full dot product of the two matrices. For the product A dot transpose(A), the correct solution is:

```
   [ 30,  70, 110, 150],
   [ 70, 174, 278, 382],
   [110, 278, 446, 614],
   [150, 382, 614, 846]]
```

(note this isn't the "correct" solution in your question, that is the solution to A dot A, rather than A dot transpose(A).

From the [block decomposition formula](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76832300/681865) which you now must be familiar, it should be obvious that the for the "upper left quadrant" of the full dot product, there is a *second* dot product of 2x2 submatrices which must be calculated and added to the first solution in this answer, i.e.

```
[[3, 4],  dot   [[3, 7],  =  [[ 25,  53],
 [7, 8]]         [4, 8]]      [ 53, 113]]
```

add the first product above

```
[[ 5, 17],   +  [[ 25,  52], = [[ 30,  70],
 [17, 61]        [ 53, 113]]    [ 70, 174]]
```

which you should be able to identify as the upper left quadrant of the correct solution.  Repeat for the other three cases and you should get:

```
[[1, 2],     dot  [[ 9, 13],  = [[ 81, 109],
 [5, 6]]          [10, 14]]     [173, 233]]

[[11, 12],   dot  [[3, 7],    = [[ 81, 173],
 [15, 16]]         [4, 8]]       [109, 233]]

[[11, 12],   dot  [[11, 12],  = [[265, 357],
 [15, 16]]         [15, 16]]     [357, 481]]
```

i.e. the correct full dot product is:

```
     5     17  |   29     41       25     53  |   81   109
    17     61  |  105    149       53    113  |  173   233
  -------------+-------------- + -------------+------------
    29    105  |  181    257       81    173  |  265   357
    41    149  |  257    365      109    233  |  357   481
```

Which you can confirm for yourself is the correct solution I showed above.

Having resolved the mathematics and what the code you adapted actually does, I would encourage you to think of how to modify the your code to do what actually you want, i.e.:

1. Change the tile size to 4. This means a single block will run the 4x4 product directly
2. Add the necessary tile motion code to perform the second set of products I showed above and add them to the solution. There is a [full example](https://github.com/NVIDIA/cuda-samples/blob/master/Samples/0_Introduction/matrixMul/matrixMul.cu) of this in the CUDA official samples repo on github.

Comment: Why did they write the kernel in that strange fashion?  What is the benefit?

Comment: I am not the authors, I don’t know. It is a pedagogical example, intended to illustrate a concept